# Displaying a 2D array in an NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I’m trying to learn Objective C by trying to convert a program I use that I wrote in C.  The program works with large 2 plus dimensional arrays and does calculations on them so I need to be able to display 2D arrays in a table format on the UI.  The best way I can come up with to do that is to convert my C-style arrays row by row to NSMutableArrays and then store the "row" NSMutableArrays in another NSMutableArray as a "stack of rows" to pass to an NSTableView.  (If there’s a better way, please let me know.)

The problem I’m having is that I can't seem to get them to store in the arrayOfArrays.  It’s just null.  I’m sure I’m making a stupid noob error and I think it has something to do with the way I’m calling the constructor, but I can’t figure it out.

Here’s my code:

```
int grid[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays;


int x=0;

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *array3 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    for (int y=0; y < 3; y++) {
        [array1 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:grid[x][y]]];
    }

    x++;
    for (int y=0; y < 3; y++) {
        [array2 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:grid[x][y]]];
    }

    x++;
    for (int y=0; y < 3; y++) {
        [array3 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:grid[x][y]]];
    }

    [arrayOfArrays addObject:array1];
    [arrayOfArrays addObject:array2];
    [arrayOfArrays addObject:array3];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return [arrayOfArrays count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn       *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{
    return [arrayOfArrays objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}

@end
```

Oh and this object is an NSTableViewSource and it is the dataSource for the NSTableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `arrayOfArrays` is an instance variable? If so, then yes, the problem you're seeing arises from the fact that you haven't initialized (created) `arrayOfArrays` before you try to add items to it.

While you could do this in `awakeFromNib`, I usually do it in `init`, and if you're not using ARC, balance the creation of `arrayOfArrays` in `init` with a `release` in `dealloc`:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
         arrayOfArrays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
   [arrayOfArrays release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

When you initialize (`init*`) an object in Objective-C, the instance variables are automatically set to `0` for primitive types and `nil` for Objective-C objects. In your original code, the lines like `[arrayOfArrays addObject:array1];` basically equated to `[nil addObject:array1];`, or in other words, sending messages to `nil`. That is allowed in Objective-C and the result is that the messages are simply ignored. The `numberOfRowsInTableView:` method would "resolve" to `return [nil count];` which would return 0, and so your app wouldn't bother calling the `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` method (and even if that were called, it would return `nil` as well).

Comment: Thanks!!  This answers my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial array is :

```
int grid[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
```

You can make a one-dimentional array by :

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays=[NSMutableArray new];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
       [arrayOfArrays  addObject:grid[i][j]];
   }
}
```

Now you can use `arrayOfArrays` as your data source.

**EDIT:**

Will this kind of representation will be fine for you?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's going to work for me.  As I understand the NSTableView, plotting a one dimensional array would give me nine rows of one, I need three rows of three.  (Unless there's a different way to format the NSTableView.)

And I still can't get *arrayOfArrays to accept any data.

Comment: I just reread my original post, I meant to say my problem was that I couldn't get anything to store in *arrayOfArrays. I left off an "'t".

Comment: check my edit, here I have 2D array, A contains 2Kids, apple, aeroplane, and second one contais 2kids, ball,.baloon.

Comment: No that wouldn't work.  It has to be in 3x3.  The example I'm using is trivial just to try and figure it out.  In the real app my grids will be 50x50 or larger.  It's a matrix app with math matrix functions and side by side comparisons.

Comment: @JoeSmith: Why bro, you started with 2D array now asking for nXn array. Not an issue, you can use NSOutlineView upto any levels. In my answer, I have shown 2x2.

Answer (score 0):

You do not *have to* convert your C array to objects. That could be an enormous unnecessary effort, unless you just want to do it. One of the lessons of Objective-C is that C is still there and still used and appropriate. Everything does not *have to* be an Object. :D

You can use the Table View Datasource methods to do the work.

`tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` and `numberOfRowsInTableView:`

In your `numberOfRowsInTableView:` implementation, just return the count of elements in the array dimension you want to use for the rows.

In your  `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` implementation, you can box the array element values as NSNumber objects or as NSString objects, then return that object. (NSNumber literals will be quite handy here)

The only clumsy part, you may still want to decide to programmatically build out the number of columns in your table based on number of elements one of your array dimensions. Add table columns or remove them as necessary.
This will provide a nice exercise in building a table view in code. It will help you in understanding some of the table view.

Well, you still will need to know the size of your C array somehow when creating it to avoid walking off the end of it... (C pitfalls...)

Comment: Thanks!!  You gave me a better way of doing this that what I was originally doing.